# Get current user id in a WP plugin with redux framework

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I'am working on a sorter plugin for WordPress, which have Redux Framework installed to manage the options of every section. The plugin uses AJAX to get the ids of all the sections in the homepage of the website, then passes those values to the plugin main file to process in a function that stores the values in the current user meta. That works well, no problem here. The function looks like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_sections_ids', 'save_sections_ids_sorting_sections' );      
function save_sections_ids_sorting_sections() {  
    //stuff here...
    $user_ide = get_current_user_id(); //it works because it is inside a hook
    update_user_meta($user_ide, "set-sections", $sections_ids);
    die();       
}
```

Then I have to get the stored values in user_meta to pass them to the Redux Field, so I wrote other function in the main file of the plugin. The function is this:

```
function get_the_db_sections_ids() { 
        $user_ide = 1; //This should be get_current_user_id() or something similar, but nothing works, not even globalizing $current_user and using get_currentuserinfo();
        $sections_ids = get_user_meta($user_ide, "set-sections", true);
        $sorter_field = array(
            "section_id" => "basic",
            'id'       => 'homepage-sections',
            'type'     => 'sorter',
            'title'    => 'Control de secciones',
            'desc'     => 'Arrastra y suelta los bloques con los nombres de las secciones, tanto para ordenarlas verticalmente como para desactivarlas o activarlas.',
            'compiler' => 'true',
            'options'  => array(
                'enabled' => array(
                ),
                'disabled'  => $sections_ids
            ),
        );
        return $sorter_field;     

}
```

As you notice in the comment in the function above, I have tried several ways, also `require_once("/../../../wp-load.php")`, but nothing happens. I tried `do_action` and `add_actions`, to create a hook, but those also use global variables, and for what I understand, the global variables do not work in functions with no hooks in plugins.

But I havent finished yet. The really tricky part is, I am calling an instance of Redux class inside the Redux config file (*sample-config.php* for the demo, I have a custom file, but it is the same).

The instance is `Redux::setField($opt_name, get_the_db_sections_ids());`

The problem this does not print anything if I call it from a function, or the function linked to the AJAX call.

As you can see, the second parameter of the instance is the function I wrote above that, and it works perfectly if I set `$user_ide` to `1`, but I want the data stores in all admins `user_meta`, in case user `1` is erased, or whatever.

Is there a way to achieve what I want, or to store the data somewhere else and get it from there. I was thinking in creating a custom table in db, and use `wpdb` to retrieve the data, but I think I can't use `wpdb` either, because it will be the same problem.

I get the feeling I'm missing something very basic, but I can't get it. Please help.

Comment: get_current_user_id() use this if you want only ID if you use this what error it gives

Comment: This is the error I get in the browser: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_currentuser_info() in C:\xampp\htdocs\futbol-americano\wp-content\plugins\sorting-sections\sorting-sections.php on line 80    The same if I use get_current_user_id() or other related to get users info.

Comment: Store your current userid in cookie and fetch that id in get_the_db_sections_ids() function.

Comment: Does not work either.$GLOBALS and $_SESSION didn't work, It has something to do with the order everyting loads, you can't use globals, or maybe I'm too tired, I'll keep triying until I make sure cookies and sessions do not work. . Maybe a JS session, but I dont think so, as I'll have the same problem, I can retrieve the user id from the JS session variable, but I can´t call the php function linked to an ajax call, because the data from ajax would not be available if I call it inside php.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_ide =  $current_user->ID;
```

You'll have to declare a global variable **$current_user**, in order to use it.

Comment: I tried that, but does not work. Well, I tried to return it instead of echoing it. Is there a difference???? I mean, the right way is echoing it inside a function????

Comment: You can just assign it to the variable **$user_ide**. I've just edited the answer, try using it

Comment: I think there's no difference, because when I use some function related to get the current user, I get a warning in the browser, saying the funcion (get_currentuserinfo, wp_get_current_user or any other related to get the current user id) is not defined, even if $current_user is globalized.

Comment: See if this helps u http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58429/how-do-i-call-wp-get-current-user-in-a-plugin-when-plugins-are-loaded-before-p

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to my problem. As I said, I couldn't get the current user id from the pligin if I tried outside an action hook or a filter hook, setting sessions and global variables didn't work, and functions hooked with WP normal hooks wouldn't set the Redux field. I reviewed the sample-config.php file inside the `ReduxFramework/sample` folder, and I found out some functions and hooks. One of them to set the entire section, but inside that section, you can set the field and it worked.

I eresed the `Redux::setField` instance, and did this in the sorter plugin main file:

```
add_filter('redux/options/' . $opt_name . '/sections', 'dynamic_section');
if ( ! function_exists( 'dynamic_section' ) ) {
    function dynamic_section( $sections ) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();            
        $sections[] = array(
            'title'  => __( 'Section via hook', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'desc'   => __( '<p class="description">This is a section created by adding a filter to the sections array. Can be used by child themes to add/remove sections from the options.</p>', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'icon'   => 'el el-paper-clip',
            'fields' => array(get_the_db_sections_ids($current_user->ID))
        );
        return $sections;
    }
} //I copied it from sample-config.php and added what's inside `"fields" =>` and the global.
```

Then I modified my array function like this:

```
function get_the_db_sections_ids($user_ide) {   //Added the parameter  
        //Erase $user_ide = 1;

        $sections_ids = get_user_meta($user_ide, "set-sections", true);
        $sorter_field = array(
            "section_id" => "basic",
            'id'       => 'homepage-sections',
            'type'     => 'sorter',
            'title'    => 'Control de secciones',
            'desc'     => 'Arrastra y suelta los bloques con los nombres de las secciones, tanto para ordenarlas verticalmente como para desactivarlas o activarlas.',
            'compiler' => 'true',
            'options'  => array(
                'enabled' => array(
                ),
                'disabled'  => $sections_ids
            ),
        );
        return $sorter_field;       
}
```

And that's it, I hope this will help somebody. Redux is great but their documentation is very far from good, so, here's one little contribution for those using the framework. And thanks to the users who tried to help me.